# Get document from mongodb based on date and month

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to get all those employee documents whose dob ISODate("2017-10-11T18:30:00.000Z") match with current date. As there is difference in years so i am not able to get directly by matching dob.
Schema Details are:

```
var employee = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    code: String,
    phone: String,
    email: String,
    status: String,
    dob: Date
})
```

So i tried with these:

- Not able to use `regex` as it works on string.
- Not able to use relational operators like `gt gte lt lte` as it is not what i am looking for.
- Tried with other mongodb operators too.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if ur date is like createdAt in which milliseconds are also stored then u need to use relational operators

Answer (score 1):

You can use date aggregation operators `$month` and `$dayOfMonth` for matching the current day and month, whatever the year:

```
db.employee.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $project: {
        day: { $dayOfMonth: "$dob" },
        month: { $month: "$dob" },
        name: true,
        code: true,
        phone: true,
        email: true,
        status: true
      }
    },
    {
      $match: {
        day: new ISODate().getDate(),
        month: new ISODate().getMonth() + 1
      }
    }
  ]
)
```